# Why is my sieve of sundaram so inefficient

Tags: python

I have been playing around with prime sieves and their performance.  I've turned to the Sundaram sieve.  My implementation is:

```
import time
from pympler import asizeof

start = time.perf_counter()
limit = 10000
upper = int(limit/2)
numbers = [i for i in range(upper)]

for j in range(1,int(upper/2)):
    i = 1
    while i <= j:
        n = i + j + (2*i*j)
        if n in numbers and n < upper:
            numbers[numbers.index(n)] = 0
        i += 1

primes = [2, 3]
for number in numbers:
    if number != 0:
        primes.append(number*2 + 1)

stop = time.perf_counter()
print(primes)
print(f'Time = {stop - start} sec')
print(f'List of numbers: {asizeof.asizeof(numbers)}')
print(f'List of primes: {asizeof.asizeof(primes)}')
```

The performance results are:

- primes below 100: 0.0002 sec
- primes below 1000: 0.0772 sec
- primes below 10000: 97.71 sec
- primes below 100000: > 30 mins (I terminated the execution)

I don't think the algorithm is inefficient and my implementation of other algorithms are much quicker than this one so it must be my code.  What part of my code is causing the run time to blow out this badly?

Comment: `n in numbers` and `numbers.index(n)` are both unnecessary linear scans. You already *know* where `n` will be, if it's anywhere in `numbers` at all.

Comment: There are a lot of awkward constructs here.  For example, instead of `numbers = [i for i in range(upper)]` just use `numbers = list(range(upper))`.  And instead of `upper = int(limit/2)` just use `upper = limit // 2`.  These aren't performance problems, but they're needlessly convoluted constructs.

Comment: This is a performance problem:  `if n in numbers`  This will search the entire `numbers` list to see if `n` is in it.  Better to use a `set` for a fast membership test.

Comment: @TomKarzes, Thanks.  I'll make those changes and retest.

Comment: @user2357112, How can those structures be replaced with something more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to perform `n in numbers`. No need to call `index` to find the index, because the index is ... `n`. Just check that `n` is in range, and just set `numbers[n]` to zero, even when it was already zero.

Besides that there are some things to improve:

- Don't add 3 explicitly, as it is added by the final loop
- Don't use float division when you need integer division (`//`)
- Don't start with `i` at 1 at each iteration. You can start at `j` and deal with the range where `i >= j` (This is how [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram) has it)
- When `n` is out of range, don't continue the loop. This becomes the exit condition of your loop.

Here is the part that needs correction:

```
upper = limit // 2  # use integer division
numbers = list(range(upper))

for j in range(1, upper//2):
    i = j  # Deal with the range from j onwards (until n exceeds)
    while True:
        n = i + j + 2 * i * j
        # No need to check membership in numbers
        if n >= upper:  # This is an exit condition. No need to continue
            break
        numbers[n] = 0
        i += 1
# Don't add 3 explicitly, as it will be added by the loop
# Use comprehension:
primes = [2] + [number*2 + 1 for number in numbers if number]
```

Comment: Thank-you.  That is blisteringly fast.  primes<100 in 12 microsec, primes<1000 in 140 microsec, primes<10000 in 2 millisec, primes<100000 in 25 millisec and primes<1000000 in 0.274 sec.  I need to learn more about list comprehensions.  Thanks again.